Regarding Fixing Outcomes in a Random Process
Here is a diagram of a stochastic process
This diagram seems to say when you fixed the time at $t_i$, you get random variable $X_i$;. and when you fix an outcome, it seems to be an entire function instead of a scalar instance.(and if its in discrete time , its an entire sequence)
I was originally thinking the sample function comes from fixing from an event (from the event space) rather than just fixing one outcome. Are the outcomes themselves functions/sequences?
And then what is an event in this context? Doesn't seem very relevant.
Wikipedia says "A probability function, , which assigns, to each event in the event space, a probability, which is a number between 0 and 1 (inclusive)."; but that doesn't seem to fit if outcomes can be functions.
(I don't have a background in measure theory or real analysis, but I have taken a few stats courses, so I prefer an answer that isn't heavy in measure theory.)
